# MMC /32 not working in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mmc

We are able to add available snap-in using MMC command in Run. When we tried to use MMC /32 command in Run, we are not able to add available snap-in. It says mmc has stopped working. In Event Receiver I can see the following error

```
Fault bucket 107747373301, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: mmc.exe
P2: 10.0.10586.0
P3: 5632d419
P4: SqlManager.dll_unloaded
P5: 2011.110.2100.60
P6: 4f35e2c3
P7: c0000005
P8: 0002d833
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\shailesh\AppData\Local\Temp\WER5862.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_mmc.exe_91fef55887df38ac829fecfe5c416e95e314aa8_3b70ea27_1d6b800e

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 75dcc229-a112-4914-8026-95007f814382
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 3a03c58a0537cf61aad7cb6ce8704ee0
```

Please provide solution

Comment: look to which program the SqlManager.dll belongs and remove it. Next time ask it on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out issue after wasting 3 days. It was due to SQL Server 2008. I am using Windows 10 and it does not support SQL Server 2008. I have uninstalled SQL Server 2008. Now everything is working fine.